# nekudos make the sound of 2 other nekudos?

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-reading, vowels-nekudot

I  am learning how to sing the torah (lain) (which is a Jewish thing to do).
It seems that all the music (notes) is in the vowels and not in the consonants/letters (consonants by themselves can not be song) the shva (אְ) is sometimes a/the (consonant letter over it) and sometimes a vowel (can be song).

So I  tried singing all of the vowels in Hebrew
they all make a single clear sound (אָ אַ אֶ אְ אִ אֻ\אוּ)
except the **the choilam (אוֹ\אֹ)**,  I was unable to sing it, it was coming out as a komats (אָ),
and **the tsairae (אֵ)**  was coming out as a segol (אֶ).

What sounds do the choilam (אוֹ\אֹ) and the tsairae (אֵ) make?
(are they [diphthongs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong) of a komats (אָ)/segol (אֶ) and a hirik (אִ)?
(if yes, do we sing it as the komats (אָ)/segol (אֶ) and in the end make a short hirik sound? (or we split the singing in half, half on the komats/segol and half on the hilik?))
or is it a vowel plus (+) a consonant, of a komats (אָ)/segol (אֶ) and a yud (י) (so then only the komats (אָ)/segol (אֶ) is sung).

Are there any Jewish sources on this?

Please correct me if i am wrong

P.S.
a quote from the cover of [this](http://www.sefer.org.il/UploadImages/000687/3105391.jpg) book

> אין הברה בלי נקוד ואין קול בלי טעם

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holam#Pronunciation

Comment: A conversation about consonant ו has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53058/discussion-on-question-by-hazoriz-nekudos-make-the-sound-of-2-other-nekudos).